# Amadeus hotel search v2.1 always returns "The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid". But I send the valid access token

Tags: amadeus

I was using this URL request "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping//shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel" and anytime I want to test this endpoint I always get that the access token is invalid.

Even in website https://developers.amadeus.com/ it always asks to sign in again and that doesn't help. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is an access issue to the Hotel Search v2 API for newly created accounts. Could you please send an email at developers@amadeus.com for the topic?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that and now I'm waiting for the answer there :)